# Multiple simultaneous UILocalNotifications

Tags: iphone, xcode, uilocalnotification

If I have two (or more) UILcalNotifications that fire more or less on the same time and the application is active in the background, I found out that:

- Two alerts are shown simultaneously to the user, one covering the other.
- When the user touches "View" on the top alert, the alert is removed from the screen, didReceiveLocalNotification is called for this notification, and the application enters the foreground.
- As soon as the top alert is removed from the screen (and the application is already in the foreground), the user sees the alert that was under it.
- However, if the user touches "View" for this alert as well, nothing happens. didReceiveLocalNotification is not called for the second notification, and the application has no way of knowing that the user wanted to view this notification as well.

If the application happens to be in the foreground when the two notifications fire, there's no problem - didReceiveLocalNotification is called for both, one after the other (no alert is shown in this case).

Is there a way to get some notification for both "View" confirmations in the above case? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm glad I found this because I am encountering the exact same issue.

If app is in background, and I have three alerts fire at the same time, choosing Yes to the OS prompt will bring app to foreground, but clicking "View" to the following two makes no calls to didReceiveLocalNotification.    Somehow the built in calendar handles this scenario fine leading me to think it was something I was doing wrong, but your finding confirms it.

I'll have to look for other solutions that might be a little more friendly to the user rather than having alerts that would seem unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the previous notification do not call the didReceiveNotification delegate method (or any other method if two or more notification pops while app in background). But you can track that previous notification as your need.

For example, if you have a app that send data to the server on clicking view of notification then on daily basis save the data into a plist (and edit it daily) that data has been sent or not by "Yes" or "No" so while a notification comes the app checks into the plist that the data for previous alarms have been sent or not. If no then it will send it at that time. So this is just an single way.

Answer (score -2):

Alert view needs to have it's delegate set (typically to self) to receive events.

Comment: I did say that the delegate is called for the first alert (but not for the second one). This is more than enough to indicate that the delegate is set properly.

Comment: If you think you have found a bug in Apple's you can submit a bug report.  I use local notifications and have not had them hit this close to cause a problem. I did find some notification problems with iOS 5 that were cleared up after loading 5.0.1